# How to use $index in ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have this code below

```
<form name="registrationForm">
<div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="participant in participantsArray">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input ng-model="datas.name[$index+1]" name="name{{$index+1}}" required verify-name>
          <span ng-if="registrationForm.name+($index+1).$dirty && registrationForm.name+($index+1).$invalid">error</span>
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and is not working, how do I need to use the $index expression in the ng-if? the ng-model, and the name are working properly ...

Comment: What you need to do in this code and what is the output of it ?

Comment: What is the angularjs version you have ?

Comment: Why can't you save the value in scope and pass it here?

Comment: It should work. I reckon you are using a older version of AngularJS 1.x

Comment: I want to add participants for an event, and the output is correct, but I don t know how to add the $index in ng-if expression

Comment: Do something like
<div ng-if="rootForm['childForm_' + $index].$valid">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dynamic fields you can use `[]` to wrap the dynamic string field.

```
registrationForm['name'+($index+1)].$dirty
```

refer the below example:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['a','b','c','d'];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="registrationForm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input ng-model="datas.name[$index+1]" name="name{{$index+1}}" required verify-name>
      <span ng-if="registrationForm['name'+($index+1)].$dirty && registrationForm['name'+($index+1)].$invalid">error</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a same problem once. What you can do is instead of `dot(.)` notation use bracket notation to access the form controls. Thats what worked for me. Below is a example. Try this this will work. Let know if you need help.

```
registrationForm['name'+($index+1)].$dirty
```

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
<span ng-if="registrationForm['name'+($index+1)].$dirty && registrationForm.name+($index+1).$invalid">error</span>
```